# A modified identity to an integration

Tags: calculus, integration, mellin-transform

$$\int_0^\infty \text{d}x \frac{\sin ax}{e^{2\pi x}-1}=\frac{1}{4}\coth \frac{a}{2}-\frac{1}{2a}$$

Is there a closed form solution to this, slightly different integral (in terms of $a$)?

$$\int_{\color\red{-\infty}}^\infty \text{d}x \frac{\sin ax}{e^{2\pi x}-\color\red{x}}$$

The manipulation is too difficult for me, but I have tried generating an inverse Mellin transform by substituting $x=iu$

That actually got me kind of far, but failed because there was still the $iu$ term left. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like not, because the usual tool using residue calculus does not seem to work here.

Comment: @yhhuang Which was why I was curious about it

Comment: $$\int_{\color{red}0}^\infty\frac{\sin ax}{e^{2\pi x}-x}~dx ~=~ \frac{i}{2~(2\pi+1)}~\bigg[H\bigg(-\frac{1+ia}{2\pi+1}\bigg) - H\bigg(-\frac{1-ia}{2\pi+1}\bigg)\bigg],$$ where ***H*** stands for the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), whose relation to the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) is well-known.